# Angularjs e2e tests with ng-scenario – checking the focus state of the input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, angularjs-e2e

I've tried:
https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery and
https://github.com/ferronrsmith/angularjs-jasmine-matchers
but looks like that it only works with jasmine framework and I'm using a ng-scenario in my app.

At first I thought that just using pseudo classes should works:

```
expect(element('#email:focus').count()).toBe(1)
```

because I found in angular-scenario.js this lines:

```
pseudos: {
...
"focus": function( elem ) {
        return elem === document.activeElement && (!document.hasFocus || document.hasFocus()) && !!(elem.type || elem.href || ~elem.tabIndex);
    },
```

but it didn't work.

I've also tried something like this:

```
element('#email').query(function(elements, done) {
            elements.focus();
            console.log( elements.is(':focus'));
            done();
        });
```

Input got a focus, but `elements.is(':focus')` always returned `false`.

Is there a simple way to check if input has a focus in Angularjs e2e tests?